# Inserting Chines/Japanese characters into phpMyAdmin show up weirdly in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

So I've started making a web application and I thought it would be nice to also have a the functionality in it to handle 'special' characters.

So I have looked around to fix this and have tried multiple things to change charset to utf8.

So I have changed my table using `ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8`

This works IF I run the SQL query in the database. 
But when I run my query using PHP code, it shows as this:

`&#25446;&#12409; &#35011;&#22734;`

My PDO connection is like this:

```
$this->dbopen = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname='. $this->dbname . '', $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );
```

I've also tried:

```
$this->dbopen = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname='. $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
```

My query goes as follows:

```
$this->query = 'INSERT INTO titles (Title, Description, Image, SoundFile) VALUES (' . $this->title . ', ' . $this->description . ', ' . $this->image . ', ' . $this->sound . ')';
```

Yet it still shows it like: 
`&#25446;&#12409; &#35011;&#22734; &#12378;&#24870;&#12402;&#23973;&#37157; &#12368;&#12356;&#39343;&#12461;&#12515;&#12400;`

I have no clue how to change this. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The problem is likely on the browser side, with the browser sending HTML encoded data, because you haven't told it how to handle encodings. See  [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze Alright thanks, I now understand how this works, and it works for me too. Yet, why is it that if I insert using SQL query in the database, it shows the characters. But when I insert into the database using PHP code, it shows the encoded format?